# Combination of MySQL, PHP and nested queries with results issues

Tags: php, mysql, subquery

I'm having a problem with some code I'm working on that serves this purpose: First, it's going to pull all the records that have the same company id and are type uploads from one table, then it's going to compare the results with the records in the second table. Normally, this isn't an issue for me...simple.

That said, my problem lies with a few factors: The queries come from a series of classes. This is the essential function being used:

```
public function query($query, $params = array())
{
    try {
        //$query = $this->build_query($query, $table);
        $params = $this->build_params($params);
        $params = $this->clean_params($query, $params);
        $this->lastquery = $this->pdo->prepare($query);
        //$this->lastquery->bindParam(':table', $this->DBPrefix . $table, PDO::PARAM_STR); // must always be set
        foreach ($params as $val)
        {
            $this->lastquery->bindParam($val[0], $val[1], @$val[2]);
        }
        $this->lastquery->execute();
        //$this->lastquery->debugDumpParams();
    }
    catch(PDOException $e) {
        //$this->lastquery->debugDumpParams();
        $this->error_handler($e->getMessage());
    }

    //$this->lastquery->rowCount(); // rows affected
}
```

Now, this is the code I've got. Please note that company_id is provided before this, $DBPrefix is defined as the prefix used on all tables of the database. Oh, and ignore the params for now...I haven't included that part yet but it will be done:

```
unlink($includeFile);
    //Start Scan Procedures
    //Step one - Read all records with type "uploads" & company_id that match current company_id
    $query =    "SELECT property_id, account_id, company_id, description, pict_url, photo_uploaded, bed, 
                        bath, sqft, built, embed_url, ext_tour_url, street, city, state, zip, unit, agent, 
                        lat, lng, mlsid, ptype, pets, furnished, length, security_deposit, pet_deposit, 
                        filename, created, type, status
                    FROM " . $DBPrefix . "properties_uploads 
                    WHERE company_id = " . $company_id . " 
                    AND type = 'uploads'";
    $db->query($query);
    $rec_to_upload = $db->result();
    $count_uploads = 0;
    foreach ($rec_to_upload as $rec) {
        $query =    "SELECT property_id
                        FROM " . $DBPrefix . "properties 
                        WHERE company_id = " . $company_id . " 
                        AND street = '" . $rec['street'] . "' 
                        AND city = '" . $rec['city'] . "' 
                        AND state = '" . $rec['state'] . "' 
                        AND unit = '" . $rec['unit'] . "'";
        if ($db->numrows() == 0) {
            //update to be an original type
            $query =    "UPDATE " . $DBPrefix . "properties_uploads 
                        SET type = 'original' 
                        WHERE property_id = " . $rec['property_id'];
            $db->query($query);
            $count_uploads++;
        } else {
            //update to be a duplicate type
            $query =    "UPDATE " . $DBPrefix . "properties_uploads 
                        SET type = 'duplicate' 
                        WHERE property_id = " . $rec['property_id'];
            $db->query($query);
        }
    }
```

When I run the SQL queries through MYSQL on their own, they run perfectly fine...and I get the correct responses every time.

When I test this, however, the $rec_to_upload results come back as a single record, rather than the 9 that should show. It doesn't run the foreach loop more than the once. If I run the numrows function we have to determine the number of rows, it's correct on the first query, but it retains its result the first time through for the inside query, then goes to 0 and bounces between 0 and 1. The properties table is empty, so it should be 0 all the way through.

I can't do $rec['city'] because it's running one record only. If I do $rec_to_upload['city'] there's a result, but this is still not a solution for multiple records.

And while it should change "type" for all records to either original or duplicate, it's leaving some as uploads.

Finally, the results of the first query seem to be pushing through twice: I'm getting both the associative results and the numerical results.

Thank you in advance for any help you can provide. If you have any questions to help clarify, I'm more than happy to answer them.

---

Additional information. It's starting at the first query with issues. I made a backup, then cleared out everything after the sql, until I was left with this:

```
//Start Scan Procedures
    //Step one - Read all records with type "uploads" & company_id that match current company_id
    $query =    "SELECT property_id, account_id, company_id, description, pict_url, photo_uploaded, bed, 
                        bath, sqft, built, embed_url, ext_tour_url, street, city, state, zip, unit, agent, 
                        lat, lng, mlsid, ptype, pets, furnished, length, security_deposit, pet_deposit, 
                        filename, created, type, status
                    FROM " . $DBPrefix . "properties_uploads 
                    WHERE company_id = " . $company_id . " 
                    AND type = 'uploads'";
    $db->query($query);
    $rec_to_upload = $db->result();
    $i = 1;
    foreach ($rec_to_upload as $rtu) {
        echo $i . '<br>';
        $i++;
    }
    echo $db->numrows();
```

Results: It recorded 62 records. There are 9 records, and there are 30 columns. It looks like it's gone through and put one record in field by field with the fields as separate records...both the associative and the numerical, rather than entering the rows in.

Comment: Based on your code, I think you have a Data issue. Your code looks OK to me. If I were you, I will use breakpoints to determine the value of `$rec_to_upload` and I would track the code , step by step. This link might help you to debugging your issue (specially the last point - breakpoints). Again I don't see any obvious issue in your code. It looks OK. if you need to setup xdebug / breakpoints or any other type of help, do not doubt to ask, I will be more than happy to help you. Good Luck! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28823498/how-to-troubleshoot-my-code-on-linux-lamp

Comment: I've been doing that, though maybe I'm missing something. I've done var_dumps and print_r all over the place, and that's how I discovered that it's giving both associative and numeric results in the query.

Comment: What I'm getting is that the query itself is correct...the way it's processing it is going off. Instead of reading rows with multiple columns, it's reading each column separately, for one record. So if I have 3 rows, 5 columns (label them A B C D and E), where usually it would be: [0] [0] A [1] B [2] C [3] D [4] E [1] [0] (and so on, ) it's reading it [This] A [0] A [That] B [1] (and so on.) Any idea why?

Answer (score 1):

Consider the following. The requirement that I've specified is slightly different from yours, but I think the principle remains the same:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS my_table;

CREATE TABLE my_table
(id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY
,name VARCHAR(12) NOT NULL
,type VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL
);

INSERT INTO my_table VALUES
(1,'Adam','unreconciled'),
(2,'Ben','reconciled'),
(3,'Charlie','reconciled'),
(4,'Adam','unreconciled'),
(5,'Ben','unreconciled'),
(6,'Dan','unreconciled');


  SELECT * FROM my_table;
  +----+---------+--------------+
  | id | name    | type         |
  +----+---------+--------------+
  |  1 | Adam    | unreconciled |
  |  2 | Ben     | reconciled   |
  |  3 | Charlie | reconciled   |
  |  4 | Adam    | unreconciled |
  |  5 | Ben     | unreconciled |
  |  6 | Dan     | unreconciled |
  +----+---------+--------------+

SELECT x.*
     , CASE WHEN y.id IS NOT NULL THEN 'duplicate' ELSE 'original' END type 
  FROM my_table x 
  LEFT 
  JOIN my_table y 
    ON y.name = x.name 
   AND y.id < x.id 
 WHERE x.type = 'unreconciled';

  +----+------+--------------+-----------+
  | id | name | type         | type      |
  +----+------+--------------+-----------+
  |  1 | Adam | unreconciled | original  |
  |  4 | Adam | unreconciled | duplicate |
  |  5 | Ben  | unreconciled | duplicate |
  |  6 | Dan  | unreconciled | original  |
  +----+------+--------------+-----------+


    UPDATE my_table x
    LEFT
    JOIN my_table y
      ON y.name = x.name
     AND y.id < x.id
     SET x.type = CASE WHEN y.id IS NOT NULL THEN 'duplicate' ELSE 'original' END
   WHERE x.type = 'unreconciled';
  Query OK, 4 rows affected (0.04 sec)

  SELECT * FROM my_table;
  +----+---------+------------+
  | id | name    | type       |
  +----+---------+------------+
  |  1 | Adam    | original   |
  |  2 | Ben     | reconciled |
  |  3 | Charlie | reconciled |
  |  4 | Adam    | duplicate  |
  |  5 | Ben     | duplicate  |
  |  6 | Dan     | original   |
  +----+---------+------------+
```

This equates to a total of one query. Not 2 queries, not 3 queries, not 1 query per loop. Just 1 query. If you can adapt this to your purpose it will be orders of magnitude faster than your present solution.

Comment: OK, I actually MIGHT be able to adapt that to my situation, , but it's a bit sketchy. I'll look into it.

Comment: Thank you. I was able to re-work the queries as you suggested, and it worked...mostly. I'm still tweaking, because I need it to also set the status at 2, but I'm close.

Comment: I have no idea what that means, but glad it looks like it's getting somewhere!

Comment: Yes, the method you showed was more advanced than I am...I count myself as a Junior level programmer, working hard to get to mid. I know the basics of joins, but I'd never dealt with cases. That's where the whole thing began to make sense once you explained it. My comment was said two seconds before I fixed that: I put the set for the status before the set case. That part of the program is working, and now I'm tweaking the next portion...remembering this case method, because it could prove useful in the future.

Comment: Still not quite working right, actually. It does well for the original, but I have to have it be matched against three columns. Can I do a CASE WHEN x.item = y.item AND x.item2 = y.item2 AND x.item3 = y.item3?

Comment: Feel free to ask a new question. Comments aren't really the right way to progress this,

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved!

What I did, considering that it was overwriting the $db->result is try several methods to prevent it ...trying to populate an array. I finally succeeded by simply doing:

```
while ($row = $db->result()) {
        $prop_data[] = $row;
    }
```

and then going from there. Thanks to all who tried to help out!

Comment: Great. Now see about joins.

Comment: No, for the purpose I need, joins wouldn't be useful, but thanks for the advice. I do know how they're used and would have used them if they were useful.

Comment: You presume that I only want to get the records that are, or are not duplicates. Which is untrue. I have multiple things I'm doing that rely on one, or both of the queries, depending on the need. Doing it my way means I don't need to write 4 additional joined sql queries later on, creating a total of 5 queries, rather than two.

Comment: I'm rather thinking joins would solve the problem with one query, instead of two (or 4, as presently written).